# What is the exact alternative API to using `CRYPTO_ctr128_encrypt` in OpenSSL 3x?

Tags: openssl

I am currently using `CRYPTO_ctr128_encrypt` in the following way:

```
CRYPTO_ctr128_encrypt(
  in, 
  out, 
  len, 
  &cipher->aes_key->key, 
  cipher->aes_key->IV, 
  buffer, 
  &num, 
  (block128_f)AES_encrypt);
```

However, this throws the warning:

`warning: 'AES_encrypt' is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]`

What is the exact alternate or workaround for `CRYPTO_ctr128_encrypt` in OpenSSL 3x to get this working without the warning?

Answer (score 0):

From the migration guide:

> Low-level encryption functions such as AES_encrypt(3) and AES_decrypt(3) have been informally discouraged from use for a long time. Applications should instead use the high level EVP APIs EVP_EncryptInit_ex(3), EVP_EncryptUpdate(3), and EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(3) or EVP_DecryptInit_ex(3), EVP_DecryptUpdate(3) and EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(3).

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man7/migration_guide.html

Refer to the EVP_Encrypt*() man page here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/EVP_EncryptInit_ex.html

To do AES-128-CTR, fetch the cipher and pass it to `EVP_EncryptInit_ex2`:

```
    EVP_CIPHER *aes = EVP_CIPHER_fetch(NULL, "AES-128-CTR", NULL);

    if (aes == NULL)
        goto err;

    /* Use the cipher using the EVP_Encrypt* APIs */

    /* Free the cipher when finished */
    EVP_CIPHER_free(aes);
```